# How do I set up Gtk on Windows for Haskell development?

Tags: haskell, gtk, msys2

So far I have installed full version from https://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html

Initially, pacman did not work so I did run as an administrator mingw64.exe found in

```
C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.2.1\msys
```

I have updated the msys2 sytem running pacman -Syu and installed all Gtk libraries. I am trying to compile https://github.com/mmsbrggr/hsudoku using stack. I have gone past the missing dll errors and now I get the following:

> haskell-gi-base-0.20.4: configure
>
> --  While building package haskell-gi-base-0.20.4 using:
>         C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab configure --with-ghc=C:\Users\Jacek\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc.EXE
>   --with-ghc-pkg=C:\Users\Jacek\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE
>   --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=C:\sr\snapshots\7eb65607\pkgdb --libdir=C:\sr\snapshots\7eb65607\lib --bindir=C:\sr\snapshots\7eb65607\bin --datadir=C:\sr\snapshots\7eb65607\share --libexecdir=C:\sr\snapshots\7eb65607\libexec --sysconfdir=C:\sr\snapshots\7eb65607\etc --docdir=C:\sr\snapshots\7eb65607\doc\haskell-gi-base-0.20.4 --htmldir=C:\sr\snapshots\7eb65607\doc\haskell-gi-base-0.20.4 --haddockdir=C:\sr\snapshots\7eb65607\doc\haskell-gi-base-0.20.4 --dependency=base=base-4.9.1.0 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.8.1 --dependency=containers=containers-0.5.7.1 --dependency=text=text-1.2.2.2-9UQZjEJZQFSGMffj1Z5g00 "--extra-include-dirs=C:\Program Files\Haskell
>   Platform\8.2.1\msys\mingw64\include"
>   "--extra-include-dirs=C:\Program Files\Haskell
>   Platform\8.2.1\msys\mingw64\include\GLIB-2.0"
>   --extra-include-dirs=C:\Users\Jacek\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\include
>   --extra-include-dirs=C:\Users\Jacek\Downloads\glib-2.54.1 "--extra-lib-dirs=C:\Program Files\Haskell
>   Platform\8.2.1\msys\mingw64\bin" "--extra-lib-dirs=C:\Program
>   Files\Haskell Platform\8.2.1\msys\usr\bin"
>   --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\Jacek\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\bin
>   --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\Jacek\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\lib
>       Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
>       Logs have been written to: C:\Users\Jacek\Documents\ExperimentingHaskell\hsudoku.stack-work\logs\haskell-gi-base-0.20.4.log
>
> ```
> Configuring haskell-gi-base-0.20.4...
> Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2.exe: Missing dependencies on foreign
> libraries:
> * Missing C libraries: gobject-2.0, glib-2.0, intl
> This problem can usually be solved by installing the system packages that
> provide these libraries (you may need the "-dev" versions). If the libraries
> are already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the
> flags --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where they are.
> ```

I am able to find includes, but I am concerned that some compiler options are wrapped in quotes. Could it be a problem?

How do I correctly add development files when I develop with Haskell and Gtk on Windows? How do I tell the Haskell compiler where it can find the includes?

> extra-include-dirs: ['C:\Program Files\Haskell
>   Platform\8.2.1\msys\mingw64\include',
>   'C:\Users\Jacek\Downloads\glib-2.54.1','C:\Program Files\Haskell
>   Platform\8.2.1\msys\mingw64\include\GLIB-2.0'] extra-lib-dirs:
>   ['C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.2.1\msys\mingw64\bin',
>   'C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.2.1\msys\usr\bin']

My extra-include dirs seem to be garbled in the compiler output.

Comment: You don't need to point to the glib sources. Haskell needs the compiled glib binary and the development includes. Usually, you get these by installing a dev version of glib, e.g. one you might find already ready-to-install on the web (easier), or one you can generate by compiling and installing the glib sources.

Comment: @chi How do I get the dev version of glib on MSYS2? That is why I went to ftp.gnome.org for sources. In the ideal world, I would need help from someone who tried the same on Windows.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no devel package on MSYS2, the includes are shipped with the main package. Just list the available packages and install glib2. https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/Using-packages

Comment: @liberforce, thanks, I have found glib2 includes using pacman -Ql mingw-w64-x86_64-glib2. Now I suspect that Haskell can't find the existing directories because the path contains spaces.

Comment: That's possible, look at http://msys2.org, at step 3 they say: `Enter Installation Folder (ASCII, no accents, spaces nor symlinks, short path) `.

Comment: So I need to try to install Haskell platform in a non-standard location?

Comment: I have tried another approach. It is documented here. https://github.com/bigos/haskell-installation , it turns out installing Haskell Platform in a nonstandard folder without spaces indeed fixes the problem of garbling the extra-libs-dirs. It was another wasted day struggling with it. It seems I have moved forward a bit, but I need a rest now.

Comment: However with different apporoach stack creates own instance of msys on a path without spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I have managed to compile and launch example Haskell program written using Gtk library.

This gist is the record of the steps taken.

https://gist.github.com/bigos/62defeec09a06f18ee38daf644af5340

Answer (score 2):

I was able to build and run the example 'Hello World' program at the [`haskell-gi` repository](https://github.com/haskell-gi/haskell-gi) on 64-bit Windows (version 10.0.16299.125) using the [Haskell Tool Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) (`stack`, version 1.6.3) as follows:

1. `stack` had previously been set up to use GHC 8.0.2 or GHC 8.2.2.
2. I followed the instructions for the [MSYS2 installer](http://www.msys2.org/) for 64-bit Windows, accepting the defaults and updating (as set out in the instructions).
3. Opening a MSYS2 shell, I then used `pacman` to install packages `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config` `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gobject-introspection` `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtksourceview3` `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-webkitgtk3`. I then returned to Windows' Command Prompt. (However, I can't rule out that I may have installed other packages.)
4. I set up the following Windows environment variables for my account (finding `Edit environment variables for your account' by typing 'env' into the Windows 10 search bar):

   ```
   PKG_CONFIG_PATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\pkgconfig
   XDG_DATA_DIRS=C:\msys64\mingw64\share
   ```

   Steps 3 and 4 were based on a [page on the `haskell-gi` wiki](https://github.com/haskell-gi/haskell-gi/wiki/Using-haskell-gi-in-Windows).
5. I added `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` near the start of the `PATH` environment variable for my account. See step 7 below about the importance of what is found first on the path.
6. I created a new Haskell project `gi-gtk-test` with a `simple` template and then moved into its folder using:

   ```
   stack new gi-gtk-test simple
   cd gi-gtk-test
   ```

   At the time of writing, that created a `stack.yaml` file with `resolver: lts-10.1` (GHC 8.2.2). A [bug in GHC 8.2.2](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14382) means that it does not work with `gi-gtk`, so I changed that to `resolver: lts-9.21` to revert to GHC 8.0.2.
7. This proved to be a vital step: Using `stack exec where -- pkg-config` and `stack exec where -- zlib1.dll` to see what versions were first encountered on the `PATH` that is set up in the `stack` environment, I made sure that the versions first encountered were those in `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\` (by changing the order of folders on my `PATH` or renaming unwanted `zlib1.dll` as `zlib1.dll.old`). (I think that other versions of the former resulted in error messages about 'missing C libraries' and other versions of the latter resulted in dialog boxes with obscure messages about dlls.)
8. I added the packages `gi-gtk` and `haskell-gi-base` to the `gi-gtk-test.cabal` file, as follows:

   ```
   executable gi-gtk-test
     hs-source-dirs:      src
     main-is:             Main.hs
     default-language:    Haskell2010
     build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                        , gi-gtk
                        , haskell-gi-base
   ```
9. I changed the contents of `Main.hs` to be the example program, namely:

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, OverloadedLabels #-}

   module Main where

   import qualified GI.Gtk as Gtk  -- package gi-gtk
   import Data.GI.Base             -- package haskell-gi-base

   main :: IO ()
   main = do
     Gtk.init Nothing
     win <- new Gtk.Window [ #title := "Hi there" ]
     on win #destroy Gtk.mainQuit
     button <- new Gtk.Button [ #label := "Click me" ]
     on button #clicked (set button [ #sensitive := False,
                                      #label := "Thanks for clicking me" ])
     #add win button
     #showAll win
     Gtk.main
   ```
10. Then, the following worked as expected to build and run the example program:

    ```
    stack build
    stack exec gi-gtk-test
    ```

Comment: With regards to item 5 I have a question. I have created a custom launcher https://gist.github.com/bigos/62defeec09a06f18ee38daf644af5340 that modifies path only for certain programs. What are the pros and cons using your approach?

Comment: @ruby_object Re Item 5, I've not yet encountered any cons of having `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` permanently on the path.